# Insert data into Hbase using Hive (JSON file)

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, hbase

I have already created a table in hbase using hive:

```
hive> CREATE TABLE hbase_table_emp(id int, name string, role string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:name,cf1:role")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "emp");
```

and created another table to load data on it :

```
hive> create table testemp(id int, name string, role string) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t';
hive> load data local inpath '/home/user/sample.txt' into table testemp;
```

and finally insert data into the hbase table:

```
hive> insert overwrite table hbase_table_emp select * from testemp;
hive> select * from hbase_table_emp;
OK
123 Ram     TeamLead
456 Silva   Member
789 Krishna Member
time taken: 0.160 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

the table looks like this in hbase:

```
hbase(main):002:0> scan 'emp'
ROW                   COLUMN+CELL                                               
 123                  column=cf1:name, timestamp=1422540225254, value=Ram       
 123                  column=cf1:role, timestamp=1422540225254, value=TeamLead  
 456                  column=cf1:name, timestamp=1422540225254, value=Silva     
 456                  column=cf1:role, timestamp=1422540225254, value=Member    
 789                  column=cf1:name, timestamp=1422540225254, value=Krishna      
 789                  column=cf1:role, timestamp=1422540225254, value=Member    
3 row(s) in 2.1230 seconds
```

Can I do the same for a JSON file :

```
 {"id": 123, "name": "Ram", "role":"TeamLead"}
 {"id": 456, "name": "Silva", "role":"Member"}
 {"id": 789, "name": "Krishna", "role":"Member"}
```

and do :

```
hive> load data local inpath '/home/user/sample.json' into table testemp;
```

please Help ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `get_json_object` function to parse the data as a JSON object.  For instance, if you create a staging table with your JSON data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS staging;
CREATE TABLE staging (json STRING);
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/local/path/to/jsonfile' INTO TABLE staging;
```

Then use `get_json_object` to extract the attributes you want to load into the table:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE hbase_table_emp SELECT
  get_json_object(json, "$.id") AS id,
  get_json_object(json, "$.name") AS name,
  get_json_object(json, "$.role") AS role
FROM staging;
```

There is more comprehensive discussion of this function [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-get_json_object).