# How to insert a list of JSONs into HBase using python

Tags: python, json, hbase, happybase

I have a list of JSON's which need to be read and inserted as JSON objects into HBase. Each JSON (could be a nested JSON) needs to be read from the list and inserted along with a new row key

```
put (key, <json>)
```

Format:

```
[ 
  {
    "x":"x-val",
    "y":222,
    "z":{
          "m":"m-val",
          "n":"n-val"
        }
  },
  {
     ..
  }
]
```

Comment: If you have Hive available, you could use that to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350258/insert-data-into-hbase-using-hive-json-file

Comment: I've tried happybase API and I can't use Hive .. Can I convert the JSON to a blob and insert into hbase?

Comment: Do you know how to use `json.loads()` in Python and have you reading [storing data](https://happybase.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user.html#storing-data) with Happybase? Please include the Python code you have tried in your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json.dumps(dict)` to convert a dictionary to a JSON string.

```
json_data = [json.dumps(x) for x in list_of_data]
```

I recommend `happybase` to connect to HBase and store the JSON, as shown [here](https://happybase.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#example). You can either loop over the `json_data` and do multiple puts, or explore happybase's `batch` functionality.