# Insert JSON file into HBase using Hive

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, hbase

I have a simple `JSON` file that I would like to insert into an `HBase table`.
My `JSON` file has the following format:

```
{  
   "word1":{  
      "doc_01":4,
      "doc_02":7
   },
   "word2":{  
      "doc_06":1,
      "doc_02":3,
      "doc_12":8
   }
}
```

The `HBase` table is called `inverted_index`, it has one column family `matches`.

I would like to use the keys `word1`,`word2`, etc as row keys and their values to be inserted in the column family `matches`.

I know that Hive supports `JSON` parsing and I've already tried it, but only when I know the keys in the `JSON` beforehand to access the records.

My problem is that I don't know what or How many words my `JSON` file contains, or How many matches each word will have (it can't be empty though).

My question: Is this even doable using hive only? If so, kindly provide some pointers on what hive queries/functions to use to achieve that.

If not, is there any alternative to tackle this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer to this [Insert data into Hbase using Hive (JSON file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350258/insert-data-into-hbase-using-hive-json-file)